# How to deploy multiple Jenkins jobs in the same node?

Tags: jenkins, nodes, google-kubernetes-engine, agent

actually i have deployed jenkins master in a GKE cluster, i have a nodepool called jenkins with autoscaling with 2 nodes max. so when i run a job in jenkins, always is using that nodepool, so, thats cool, but, the problem that i have actually, is that when i run a job, jenkins is using 1 node per job, instead of use 1 node per two or more jobs, if a do a kubectl describe node nodename, i can see that i have only 1 jenkins agent deployed in each kubernetes node.

How can i fix this and use 1 node for more than 1 jenkins agent at the same time? because actually im "underusing" my jenkins nodes, because 1 job per node only use half of node resources.

Example of kubectl describe node jenkinsnode (you can see that only have 1 jenkins pod in that node):

```
  Namespace                   Name                                               CPU Requests  CPU Limits   Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                               ------------  ----------   ---------------  -------------  ---
  jenkins                     atlas-test-atlas-full-tests-2-mrc47-2h7fb-t1vdn    850m (21%)    1250m (31%)  1536Mi (54%)     2560Mi (91%)   118s
  kube-system                 fluentbit-gke-f296j                                100m (2%)     0 (0%)       200Mi (7%)       500Mi (17%)    5m8s
  kube-system                 gke-metadata-server-nc58q                          100m (2%)     100m (2%)    100Mi (3%)       100Mi (3%)     5m7s
  kube-system                 gke-metrics-agent-q6xl4                            3m (0%)       0 (0%)       50Mi (1%)        50Mi (1%)      5m8s
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-gke-develop-jenkins-eb1faad2-9m00       100m (2%)     0 (0%)       0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5m7s
  kube-system                 netd-s6v8s                                         0 (0%)        0 (0%)       0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5m7s
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Overall, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Kubernetes plugin for Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/#plugin-content-kubernetes-plugin-for-jenkins), with it you can create a Kubernetes Pod for each agent started:

> The Kubernetes plugin allocates Jenkins agents in Kubernetes pods.
> Within these pods, there is always one special container jnlp that is
> running the Jenkins agent. Other containers can run arbitrary
> processes of your choosing, and it is possible to run commands
> dynamically in any container in the agent pod.

Example:

pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: maven
    image: maven:3.8.1-jdk-8
    command:
    - sleep
    args:
    - 99d
  - name: golang
    image: golang:1.16.5
    command:
    - sleep
    args:
    - 99d
```

Jenkinsfile

```
podTemplate(yaml: readTrusted('pod.yaml')) {
  node(POD_LABEL) {
    // ...
  }
}
```